# Android sqlite order by a substring

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, mediastore

I'm trying to order this set of rows, by the last path segment:

`_data: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures
_data: /storage/emulated/0/Music
_data: /storage/emulated/0/Notifications
_data: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/picture.png`

The result I'm wishing to achieve is

`Music
Notifications
Pictures
picture.png`

I've tried to play around with sqlite `instr` function but unfortunately Android sqlite doesn't contain `instr(x,y,z)`, which would allow to fetch the last string after `/`. It only contains `instr(x,y)`.

How may I achieve this behaviour directly from the database query?

Comment: you can notice that you don't actually need to substr, since the prefix is always the same

Comment: @njzk2 in the sample it is the same, but the solution needs to be generic.